# Can't receive any notification from AmazonSNS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am not sure why I can't receive any notification from AmazonSNS. Am I missing something in my code? I am using the latest version of AWSSDK for Windows Store App by the way.

Here's my code so far.

```
d("init AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient");
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient sns = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient("secret", "secret", RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

d("get notification channel uri");
string channel = string.Empty;
var channelOperation = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
channelOperation.PushNotificationReceived += ChannelOperation_PushNotificationReceived;

d("creating platform endpoint request");
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest epReq = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
epReq.PlatformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:X413XXXX310X:app/WNS/Device";
d("token: " + channelOperation.Uri.ToString());
epReq.Token = channelOperation.Uri.ToString();

d("creat plateform endpoint");
CreatePlatformEndpointResponse epRes = await sns.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(epReq);

d("endpoint arn: " + epRes.EndpointArn);

d("subscribe to topic");
SubscribeResponse subsResp = await sns.SubscribeAsync(new SubscribeRequest()
{
    TopicArn = "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:X413XXXX310X:Topic",
    Protocol = "application",
    Endpoint = epRes.EndpointArn
});

private void ChannelOperation_PushNotificationReceived(Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannel sender, Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("receiving something");
}
```

Comment: in your code your provide instead string "secret" real amazon secret key?

Comment: of course not :) I have the real secret key.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually working after enabling Toast on .appxmanifest

I get notified everytime I publish a RAW message from Amazon SNS console. I am not receiving a JSON though which I actually need.